# How do I make ResourceManager use the right fallback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fallback, resourcemanager

In a project there are three resource files `Exceptions.resx` `Exceptions.en.resx` `Exceptions.de.resx`.
At some point it is necessary to retrieve some string resource. To do so I use `Exceptions.ResourceManager.GetString(name, culture)`.
The problem is that if I ask for some key that doesn't exist in `Exceptions.de.resx` I receive a value from `Exceptions.en.resx`, and not from `Exceptions.resx`.
Is it the expected behavior? I would expect `Exceptions.resx` to be a fallback. What am I missing?

P.S. it is a asp.net core project if it does change anything.